# 'Launch More Like This" will interfere with the running instance in any sense?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**'Launch More Like This**" option in *AWS EC2* will interfere with the running instance?

I know that creating an image (*AMI*) of a running instance will shut it down for a few seconds to actually make the image's copy.

My question is: **Will 'Launch More Like This" will also do shutdown/restart the instance?**

I feel like it's only some configurations but I would like to make sure since this a production instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, AWS just uses the same parameters as the existing machine.  So the machine size, security group, and so on use the same parameters.  Note that it explicitly does **not** copy anything over from a existing instance.  If your existing instance has had user data tied to it then that will be used for the new instance but otherwise nothing else will be copied or taken from the existing machine.